# How to ask to ros the service parameter data type

Tags: ros, parameter, rosservice

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning ROS from the Wiki site and doing some commandos on the terminal to improve my understanding about it:

I would like to know what are the parameters of a **Rosservice**, I am doing something like:

> $rosclient@rosclient-VirtualBox:~$
> rosservice list

I get:

> /clear /kill /reset
> /rosout/get_loggers
>
> /rosout/set_logger_level /spawn
>
> /teleop_turtle/get_loggers
>
> /teleop_turtle/set_logger_level
>
> /turtle1/set_pen
>
> /turtle1/teleport_absolute
>
> ...etc etc

then I do:

> $rosclient@rosclient-VirtualBox:~$
> rosservice info
> /turtle1/teleport_absolute

and  I get:

> Node: /turtlesim
>
> URI: rosrpc://rosclient-VirtualBox:40839
>
> Type: turtlesim/TeleportAbsolute
>
> Args: x y theta

but I need to know what x,y theta are... are float, ints or what (please note this example is pretty trivial to infer the data type, but I am looking for somthing like **rosmsg** )

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258003/how-to-ask-to-ros-the-service-parameter-data-type/) by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on ROS Answers with karma: 424 on 2017-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rossrv` offers exactly the same sub-commands as `rosmsg`. See [its wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosmsg#rossrv).

For your particular case,

```
$ rossrv 
list      md5       package   packages  show      
$ rossrv show turtlesim/TeleportAbsolute
float32 x
float32 y
float32 theta
---
```

Or without package name:

```
$ rossrv show TeleportAbsolute                                                                                                                                                            
[turtlesim/TeleportAbsolute]:
float32 x
float32 y
float32 theta
---
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ](https://answers.ros.org/users/29728/%CF%86xoc%C4%99-%EC%9B%83-%D0%BFepe%C3%BApa-%E3%83%84/) on 2017-03-28**:
Thanks a lot!